# Java repaint() makes second canvas drawing not appear

Tags: java, awt, repaint

I have been making a paint program, and I put in a color strip with every color in the spectrum, so that the user can just click anywhere, and it will give them (roughly) the desired Color. My issue is that it works perfectly, but when the program runs, you have to resize the window (AKA invoke repaint()) a few times until it actually works. This is some lengthy code, but you can skim through the odious boolean resets.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class PaintHomework extends Applet implements ActionListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
{
    Canvas c1;
    Canvas c2;


    Graphics myG;
    Graphics myG2;

    TextField t1;
    TextField currentColor;
    TextField currentMode;
    TextField currentShape;

    int xForStraightLine=0;
    int yForStraightLine=0;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    int counter = 0;
    int x11=1;
    int x22=0;
    int y11=1;
    int y22=200;

    int x1;
    int y1;
    int x2;
    int y2;
    int xSize=0;
    int ySize=0;

    float num1 = (float).01;
    float num2 = (float)1.0;
    float num3 = (float)1.0;
    float hueNum=0;

    int penSize = 10;
    String text = "";

    Button red;
    Button blue;
    Button green;

    Button oval;
    Button rect;
    Button sprayCan;
    Button straightLine;
    Button filled;
    Button empty;
    Button free;
    Button dragOval;
    Button dragRect;

    Button reset;

    boolean ovalTime;
    boolean rectTime;
    boolean sprayCanTime;
    boolean straightLineTime;
    boolean filledTime;
    boolean emptyTime;
    boolean freeTime;
    boolean dragOvalTime;
    boolean dragRectTime;


    public void init()
    {
        this.setSize(1350,651);

        c1 = new Canvas();
        add(c1);
        c1.setSize(900,450);


        c1.addMouseListener(this);
        c1.addMouseMotionListener(this);

        red = new Button("Red");
        add(red);
        red.addActionListener(this);
        red.setBackground(Color.red);
        red.addMouseListener(this);

        blue = new Button("Blue");
        add(blue);
        blue.addActionListener(this);
        blue.setBackground(Color.blue);
        blue.addMouseListener(this);

        green = new Button("Green");
        add(green);
        green.addActionListener(this);
        green.setBackground(Color.green);
        green.addMouseListener(this);


        oval = new Button("Oval");
        add(oval);
        oval.addActionListener(this);

        rect = new Button("Square");
        add(rect);
        rect.addActionListener(this);

        sprayCan = new Button("Spray Can");
        add(sprayCan);
        sprayCan.addActionListener(this);

        filled = new Button("Filled");
        add(filled);
        filled.addActionListener(this);

        empty = new Button("Empty");
        add(empty);
        empty.addActionListener(this);

        free = new Button("Free");
        add(free);
        free.addActionListener(this);

        straightLine = new Button("Straight Line");
        add(straightLine);
        straightLine.addActionListener(this);

        dragOval = new Button("Drag Oval");
        add(dragOval);
        dragOval.addActionListener(this);

        dragRect = new Button("Drag Square");
        add(dragRect);
        dragRect.addActionListener(this);

        t1 = new TextField("10");
        add(t1);
        t1.addActionListener(this);

        currentColor = new TextField("Black");
        add(currentColor);
        currentColor.addActionListener(this);

        currentMode = new TextField("Free");
        add(currentMode);
        currentMode.addActionListener(this);

        currentShape = new TextField("Oval");
        add(currentShape);
        currentShape.addActionListener(this);

        reset = new Button("Reset");
        add(reset);
        reset.addActionListener(this);

        c2 = new Canvas();
        add(c2);
        c2.addMouseListener(this);
        c2.setSize(900,200);




        ovalTime = false;
        rectTime = false;
        sprayCanTime = false;
        straightLineTime = false;
        filledTime = false;
        emptyTime = true;
        freeTime = true;
        dragOvalTime = false;
        dragRectTime = false;

        myG = c1.getGraphics();
        myG2 = c2.getGraphics();

        currentShape.setText("");
        drawRainbow();


    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource()==red)
        {
            myG.setColor(Color.red);
        }
        if(e.getSource()==blue)
        {
            myG.setColor(Color.blue);
        }
        if(e.getSource()==green)
        {
            myG.setColor(Color.green);
        }
        if(e.getSource()==oval)
        {
            ovalTime = true;
            rectTime = false;

            freeTime = false;
            straightLineTime = false;
            emptyTime = true;

            currentMode.setText("Empty");
            currentShape.setText("Oval");
        }
        if(e.getSource()==rect)
        {
            ovalTime = false;
            rectTime = true;
            currentShape.setText("Square");
        }
        if(e.getSource()==sprayCan)
        {
            sprayCanTime = true;
            straightLineTime = false;
            filledTime = false;
            emptyTime = false;
            freeTime = false;
            dragOvalTime = false;
            dragRectTime = false;
            currentMode.setText("Spray");
            currentShape.setText("");
        }
        if(e.getSource()==straightLine)
        {
            straightLineTime = true;
            sprayCanTime = false;           
            filledTime = false;
            emptyTime = false;
            freeTime = false;
            dragOvalTime = false;
            dragRectTime = false;
            currentMode.setText("Line");
        }
        if(e.getSource()==filled)
        {
            filledTime = true;
            sprayCanTime = false;
            straightLineTime = false;
            emptyTime = false;
            freeTime = false;
            dragOvalTime = false;
            dragRectTime = false;
            currentMode.setText("Filled");
        }
        if(e.getSource()==empty)
        {
            emptyTime = true;
            sprayCanTime = false;
            straightLineTime = false;
            filledTime = false;
            freeTime = false;
            dragOvalTime = false;
            dragRectTime = false;
            currentMode.setText("Empty");
        }
        if(e.getSource()==free)
        {
            freeTime = true;
            sprayCanTime = false;
            straightLineTime = false;
            filledTime = false;
            emptyTime = false;
            dragOvalTime = false;
            dragRectTime = false;
            currentMode.setText("Free");

        }
        if(e.getSource()==dragOval)
        {
            dragOvalTime = true;
            freeTime = false;
            sprayCanTime = false;
            straightLineTime = false;
            filledTime = false;
            emptyTime = false;
            dragRectTime = false;
            currentMode.setText("Drag Oval");
        }
        if(e.getSource()==dragRect)
        {
            dragRectTime = true;
            dragOvalTime = false;
            freeTime = false;
            sprayCanTime = false;
            straightLineTime = false;
            filledTime = false;
            emptyTime = false;
            currentMode.setText("Drag Square");
        }
        if(e.getSource()==t1)
        {
            text = t1.getText();
            penSize = Integer.parseInt(text);
        }
        if(e.getSource()==reset)
        {

            myG.setColor(Color.white);
            myG.fillRect(0, 0, 900, 450);
            myG.setColor(Color.black);

            ovalTime = true;
            rectTime = false;
            sprayCanTime = false;
            straightLineTime = false;
            filledTime = false;
            emptyTime = true;
            freeTime = true;
            dragOvalTime = false;
            dragRectTime = false;

            t1.setText("10");
            penSize = 10;

            currentColor.setText("Black");
            currentMode.setText("Free");
            currentShape.setText("");

        }


    }


    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        c1.setLocation(0,0);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, 901, 450);
        free.setLocation(1050, 250);
        reset.setLocation(1275, 250);
        straightLine.setLocation(950,250);
        t1.setLocation(1100, 50);
        t1.setSize(40,20);
        g.drawString("Press Enter After Changing Size", 1050, 30);
        g.drawRect(1049, 18, 177, 20);
        currentColor.setLocation(990, 90);
        currentMode.setLocation(1200, 90);
        currentMode.setSize(65,20);
        currentShape.setLocation(1095, 90);
        dragOval.setLocation(1100,250);
        dragRect.setLocation(1175,250);

        c2.setLocation(0,495);
        drawRainbow();

    }

    public void drawRainbow()
    {
        counter = 0;
        x11=1;
        x22=0;
        y11=1;
        y22=200;
        num1 = (float).01;
        num2 = (float)1.0;
        num3 = (float)1.0;

        while(counter < 1349)
        {
            myG2.setColor(Color.getHSBColor(num1, num2, num3));
            myG2.drawLine(x11,y11,x22,y22);
            num1=(float)(num1+.001);
            x11++;
            x22++;
            counter++;
        }
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
    {


    }



    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) 
    {

    }



    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {

    }



    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource()==red)
        {
            red.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        }

        if(e.getSource()==blue)
        {
            blue.setBackground(Color.magenta);
        }
        if(e.getSource()==green)
        {
            green.setBackground(Color.pink);
        }       
        if(straightLineTime)
        {
            xForStraightLine = e.getX();
            yForStraightLine = e.getY(); 
        }
        if(ovalTime)
        {
            if(!freeTime)
            {
                if(emptyTime)
                {
                    myG.drawOval(e.getX(),e.getY(),penSize,penSize);
                }
                if(filledTime)
                {
                    myG.fillOval(e.getX(),e.getY(),penSize,penSize);
                }
            }
        }
        if(rectTime)
        {
            if(!freeTime)
            {
                if(emptyTime)
                {
                    myG.drawRect(e.getX(),e.getY(),penSize,penSize);
                }
                if(filledTime)
                {
                    myG.fillRect(e.getX(),e.getY(),penSize,penSize);
                }
            }   
        }
        if(freeTime)
        {
            x = e.getX();
            y = e.getY();
            ovalTime = false;
            rectTime = false;
            currentShape.setText("");
        }
        if(dragOvalTime || dragRectTime)
        {
            x1=e.getX();
            y1=e.getY();
        }

        if(e.getSource()==c2)
        {
            hueNum = e.getX();
            hueNum = hueNum+70;
            hueNum = (float)(hueNum*.001);
            myG.setColor(Color.getHSBColor(hueNum,num2,num3));
        }

    }



    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        if(e.getSource()==red)
        {
            red.setBackground(Color.red);
            currentColor.setText("Red");
        }

        if(e.getSource()==blue)
        {
            blue.setBackground(Color.blue);
            currentColor.setText("Blue");
        }
        if(e.getSource()==green)
        {
            green.setBackground(Color.green);
            currentColor.setText("Green");
        }
        if(straightLineTime)
        {
            myG.drawLine(xForStraightLine, yForStraightLine, e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
        if(dragOvalTime)
        {
            x2=e.getX();
            y2=e.getY();
            xSize = Math.abs(x2-x1);
            ySize = Math.abs(y2-y1);

            if(x2>x1 && y2>y1) //if top left to bottom right
            {
                myG.drawOval(x1,y1,xSize,ySize);
            }
            if(x2<x1 && y2<y1) //if bottom right to top left
            {
                myG.drawOval(x2,y2,xSize,ySize);
            }
            if(x2<x1 && y2>y1) //if top right to bottom left
            {
                myG.drawOval(x2,y1,xSize,ySize);
            }
            if(x2>x1 && y2<y1) //if bottom left to top right
            {
                myG.drawOval(x1, y2, xSize, ySize);
            }

            /* There are 4 possible cases, originally it draws on the initial press point.
             * Judge each of the cases be seeing which coordinates are larger than others, to know whether to start on draw or end point.
             */
        }
        if(dragRectTime)
        {
            x2=e.getX();
            y2=e.getY();
            xSize = Math.abs(x2-x1);
            ySize = Math.abs(y2-y1);

            if(x2>x1 && y2>y1) //if top left to bottom right
            {
                myG.drawRect(x1,y1,xSize,ySize);
            }
            if(x2<x1 && y2<y1) //if bottom right to top left
            {
                myG.drawRect(x2,y2,xSize,ySize);
            }
            if(x2<x1 && y2>y1) //if top right to bottom left
            {
                myG.drawRect(x2,y1,xSize,ySize);
            }
            if(x2>x1 && y2<y1) //if bottom left to top right
            {
                myG.drawRect(x1, y2, xSize, ySize);
            }

            /* There are 4 possible cases, originally it draws on the initial press point.
             * Judge each of the cases be seeing which coordinates are larger than others, to know whether to start on draw or end point.
             */
        }
    }



    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) 
    {
        if(ovalTime)
        {
            if(emptyTime)
            {
                myG.drawOval(arg0.getX(),arg0.getY(),penSize,penSize);
            }
            if(filledTime)
            {
                myG.fillOval(arg0.getX(),arg0.getY(),penSize,penSize);
            }
        }
        if(rectTime)
        {
            if(emptyTime)
            {
                myG.drawRect(arg0.getX(),arg0.getY(),penSize,penSize);
            }
            if(filledTime)
            {
                myG.fillRect(arg0.getX(),arg0.getY(),penSize,penSize);
            }
        }
        if(sprayCanTime)
        {
            myG.drawOval(arg0.getX(),arg0.getY(),penSize,penSize);
            myG.fillOval(arg0.getX(),arg0.getY(),penSize,penSize);
        }

        if(freeTime)
        {
            myG.drawLine(arg0.getX(), arg0.getY(), x, y);
            x = arg0.getX();
            y = arg0.getY();
        }

    }



    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) 
    {


    }



}
```

Comment: 1) *"This is some lengthy code, but you can skim through the odious boolean resets."*  Alternately I can just ignore this question and  continue to the next, where the person trimmed the code. For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) If the teacher specified AWT, they are not fit to teach.  If not, use Swing.  3) Code frames rather than applets at this stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting program.  Try this.

Change:

```
c2 = new Canvas();
```

To:

```
c2 = new Canvas() {
    public void paint(final Graphics g) {
        drawRainbow(g);
    }
};
```

Use the passed graphics object g in drawRainbow(Graphics g) and remove any calls to drawRainbow() as in:

```
public void drawRainbow(final Graphics g) {
...
   g.setColor(Color.getHSBColor(num1, num2, num3));
   g.drawLine(x11, y11, x22, y22);
...
```

EDIT: Heed the advice concerning Graphics in the answer you accepted.

Comment: Thank you so much, I threw that in and it worked. I'll have to do some more research into how Graphics and final work, but thank you so much for the help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

NEVER maintain ANY reference to any `Graphics` context you did not create yourself

This...

```
myG = c1.getGraphics();
myG2 = c2.getGraphics();
```

Is not how custom painting is performed.  Apart from the fact that `getGraphics` can return `null`, these are just "snapshots" of the last paint cycle.  More over, there is no gurentee that the reference returned by these methods will be the same reference use on the next paint cycle.

I'm not sure why you're using AWT over Swing, but that's your choice.

Create yourself a custom version of `Canvas` and override it's `paint` method.  Perform all you painting in this method, using the `Graphics` context past to it.  Don't forget to call `super.paint` first!

Have a read of [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details

Comment: Honestly, I'm not that good at programming, as I am in a High School class, so I use AWT because I was never taught Swing. I am not too sure how I will make my own custom version of Canvas, but I guess Google will aid me there. Also, I have no clue what super.paint means to be honest. Thanks for running through that horrible lump of code for me though.

Comment: `public class MyCanvas extends Canvas {...}` - Basic OO.  Start with [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html) and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) then have a go at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)